# Визуализация цикла

Tags: javascript, циклы, визуализация

Как показать пользователю процесс работы js скрипта. К примеру у меня есть цикл, который выполняется около 5 минут. Как можно показать это выполнение в виде полосы загрузки или чего-то такого? Или выводить некоторые данные в процессе работы цикла на экран.
Есть пример реализованный на setInterval

```js
var start = document.getElementById("start");
      
start.onclick = function() {
  var div = document.getElementById("load"),
    i = 0;
  timer = setInterval(function() {
    div.style.width = i + "px";
    i++;
    if (i == 1000) {
     alert("end");
     clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }, 4);
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 0px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="load"></div>
<input type="button" id="start" value="Старт">
```

Но скорость выполнения данной штуки очень медленная

Comment: Добавить в HTML-разметку "полосу загрузки или чего-то такое", и на каждой итерации цикла обновлять значение/состояние этого "что-то такое". Вопрос слишком общий.

Comment: Если бы это было так просто. Загвоздка в том, что в процессе цикла  значение/состояние элемента HTML-разметки не будет меняться. А поменяется только после того, как цикл закончит свою работу, то есть выведется результат

Comment: Меняться будет, если организовать цикл асинхронно (например, через `setInterval` или `requestAnimationFrame`). Тем более что современные браузеры в любом случае не позволят синхронному коду выполняться 5 минут, вешая страницу... Повторюсь, вопрос слишком общий - отредактируйте и конкретизируйте его, чтобы была возможность однозначного ответа. Если Вы пытались решить задачу самостоятельно, то очень полезен будет [mcve].

Comment: Наверное проще всего сделать надпись, что-то типа "подождите 5 минут" и спиннер, если нужен легкореализуемый способ.

Comment: Самый лучший способ - сделать **WebWorker**. Так у вас не будет тормозить интерфейс, будет обновляться **HTML**, скрипт может работать сколь угодно долго.

Comment: *«скорость выполнения данной штуки очень медленная»* - @RealPeha, Вы имеете в виду саму скорость обновления такого прогрессбара, или то что при вычислениях он периодически замирает и движется рывками?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем понимаю, что именно Вам не нравится в реализации на `setInterval`, но предполагаю что дело в увеличении задержки браузером (когда помимо обновления стилей, в коде что-то считается)... поэтому, вот пример с использованием `requestAnimationFrame`:

```js
const ITERATIONS = 100,   // количество тестовых итераций 
      DELAY_MS   = 80;    // задержка на каждой итерации (синхронный код)

var dataArr = [],         // массив, который будет заполняться во время теста
    prBar = document.getElementById('pb-test'),             // элемент прогрессбара 
    btnStart = document.getElementById('start');            // элемент кнопки запуска теста 
    
// добавляем обработчик клика, который запустит выполнение
btnStart.addEventListener('click', doSomething);

// функция, содержащая код одной итерации 
function doSomething() {
  if (dataArr.length < ITERATIONS) {                        // проверяем условие, по которому обработка завершается 
    dataArr.push(calc());                                   // какие-либо вычисления 
    let percent = dataArr.length / ITERATIONS * 100 + '%';  // считаем процент выполнения 
    prBar.style.setProperty('--value', percent);            // устанавливаем процентное значение CSS-переменной 
    dirtyHackForRedrawInWebkit(prBar);                      // костыль для перерисовки (см. ниже)
    requestAnimationFrame(doSomething);                     // планируем следующую итерацию 
  } else {
    alert('Готово!'); 
    dataArr.splice(0, dataArr.length);
  }
}

// функция, выполняющая роль тестовой "нагрузки"
function calc() {
  let endTime = performance.now() + DELAY_MS;
  while (endTime > performance.now()) {} 
}

// по какой-то непонятной причине, WebKit-браузеры сами не перерисовывают элемент. Данная функция заставляет сделать это.
// и дело не в использовании CSS-переменной или псевдокласса (я проверял это, меняя стили у дочернего div'а - то же самое)
function dirtyHackForRedrawInWebkit(el) {
  el.style.display = 'table';  el.clientHeight; el.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
.progress-bar {
  --value: 0%; 
  width: 300px; height: 30px; 
  background-color: #eee; 
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px 0 #0002;
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
}
.progress-bar:after {
  content: ''; display: block; 
  width: var(--value); height: 100%; 
  background: linear-gradient(#7cd, #49a); 
  transition: width 0.2s linear; 
}
```

```html
<div id="pb-test" class="progress-bar"></div>
<button id="start">Старт</button>
```

*Прогрессбар выполнен с использованием CSS3 переменных. Они [не поддерживаются в IE и Edge](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables) (у последнего поддержка кагбэ есть, но не полная, и с проблемами).*

---

#### Upd.:

- Изменил нагрузочную функцию, чтобы задержка не зависела от скорости компа :)
- Добавил обход бага отрисовки, свойственного WebKit-браузерам. За примененный хак - [спасибо западным коллегам](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3485654).

Предыдущая версия сниппета (где этот баг повторяется) ниже, под спойлером.

```js
const ITERATIONS = 100;  // количество тестовых итераций 

var dataArr = [],         // массив, который будет заполняться во время теста
    prBar = document.getElementById('pb-test'),             // элемент прогрессбара 
    btnStart = document.getElementById('start');            // элемент кнопки запуска теста 
    
// добавляем обработчик клика, который запустит выполнение
btnStart.addEventListener('click', doSomething);

// функция, содержащая код одной итерации 
function doSomething() {
  if (dataArr.length < ITERATIONS) {                        // проверяем условие, по которому обработка завершается 
    dataArr.push(calc());                                   // какие-либо вычисления 
    let percent = dataArr.length / ITERATIONS * 100 + '%';  // считаем процент выполнения 
    prBar.style.setProperty('--value', percent);            // устанавливаем процентное значение CSS-переменной 
    requestAnimationFrame(doSomething);                     // планируем следующую итерацию 
  } else {
    alert('Готово!'); 
    dataArr.splice(0, dataArr.length);
  }
}

// функция, выполняющая роль тестовой "нагрузки" - просто многократно считает синус 
function calc() {
  for (var sin, i = 0; i < 1e6; i++) 
    sin = Math.sin(Math.random()); 
  return sin; 
}
```

```css
.progress-bar {
  --value: 0%; 
  width: 300px; height: 30px; 
  background-color: #eee; 
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px 0 #0002;
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
}
.progress-bar:after {
  content: ''; display: block; 
  width: var(--value); height: 100%; 
  background: linear-gradient(#7cd, #49a); 
  transition: width 0.2s linear; 
}
```

```html
<div id="pb-test" class="progress-bar"></div>
<button id="start">Старт</button>
```